# CodeIgniter - upload directory is invalid

Tags: php, codeigniter, web, upload

I again need your help!

My codeigniter upload function doesn't work correctly, it's returning the message:"invalid upload path".

My form is a customer register form, with personal data and a field to upload personal files, if form validation is true does the upload.

**Follows part of my controller code that is responsible for upload:**

```html
            //MAKE THE UPLOAD DIR BASE WITH PREVIOUS DEFINED NAME
            mkdir("./uploads/$dirname", 0777);
            //UPLOAD CUSTOMERS FILES
            $config['upload_path']   = "./uploads/$dirname";
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png|pdf';
            $config['max_size']      = 2048;
            $config['max_width']     = 1920;
            $config['max_height']    = 1280;

            $this->load->library('upload', $config);

            if (!$this->upload->do_upload('userfile')) {
                $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
                //SET SESSION MESSAGE FOR THE USER
                $this->session->set_flashdata('upload',$error);
            } else {
                $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
                //SET SESSION MESSAGE FOR THE USER
                $this->session->set_flashdata('upload','Upload success!');
            }
```

My view return success to the data in the database and error to upload.

**Below my directory structure:**

web_administration
    |
    |-application
    |-src
    |-**uploads**
        |
        |-**customer_directory** 
    |
    |-user_guide

Comment: if you try with `APPPATH . "uploads/$dirname/"`

Comment: Since your uploads directory is outside Application, you should change your upload path to `FCPATH . "uploads/$dirname/"` Use this path to create the directory as well.

Comment: When I try FCPATH or APPPATH, the directory bars are reversed:
C:\Users\Edvainer\Dropbox\htdocs\web_administration\uploads/08890351640